# elasticsearch-mesos not getting listed under frameworks of mesosUI

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, apache-zookeeper, mesos, mesosphere

Iam trying to run elasticsearch-mesos on mesos.My machine is running ubuntu 14.04. I have running mesos cluster installed with mesosphere packages by following these [instructions](https://mesosphere.com/docs/tutorials/install_ubuntu_debian/). When I run test frameworks it gets lister under frameworks of mesosUI but for elasticsearch-mesos its not getting listed under mesos webUI. I want to run elasticsearch-mesos on top of mesos. I followed instructions given [here](https://github.com/mesosphere/elasticsearch-mesos). When I run `./elasticsearch-mesos` I am getting a message in terminal

```
I0108 17:24:01.898540 23861 group.cpp:385] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
```

I tried running ./elasticsearch-mesos on both mesos masters and slaves.

The last few lines of terminal output is given below

```
2015-01-08 17:24:01,881:23844(0x7f175bfff700):ZOO_INFO@zookeeper_init@786: Initiating       
client connection, host=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=10000 watcher=0x7f1762a3e6a0 
sessionId=0 sessionPasswd=<null> context=0x7f1710002530 flags=0
I0108 17:24:01.881392 23858 sched.cpp:137] Version: 0.21.1
2015-01-08 17:24:01,881:23844(0x7f172b7fe700):ZOO_INFO@check_events@1703: initiated  
connection to server [127.0.0.1:2181]
2015-01-08 17:24:01,897:23844(0x7f172b7fe700):ZOO_INFO@check_events@1750: session 
establishment complete on server [127.0.0.1:2181], sessionId=0x14ac7c469270006,    
negotiated timeout=10000
I0108 17:24:01.898455 23861 group.cpp:313] Group process (group(1)@127.0.1.1:38668) 
connected to ZooKeeper
I0108 17:24:01.898509 23861 group.cpp:790] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, 
cancels, datas) = (0, 0, 0)
I0108 17:24:01.898540 23861 group.cpp:385] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the README at https://github.com/mesosphere/elasticsearch-mesos,
you may need to modify `mesos.master.url` to point to the same ZK url that the Mesos master is using (maybe not localhost). If you're using a single-master Mesos cluster, you can skip the ZK url and point this parameter directly to the Mesos master.

Please also note that the elasticsearch framework is a bit outdated, so use with caution

Comment: thanks for the reply. I solved it. But still elasticsearch is not getting listing under frameworks of Mesos WebUI. I got framework registered messages in terminal.